# How can i restart livedata builder function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to use `livedata` builder functions. Indeed, it's so easy in use, but actually I can't understand how I can restart my coroutine. Below my part of code:

```
val topStoriesResult : LiveData<UIState<TopStoryWrapper>> = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    topStoriesRepository.getTopStoriesSetWrapper().apply {
        emit(UIState.Loading)
        onFailure { emit(UIState.NoData) }
        onSuccess { emit(UIState.HasData(it)) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`liveData` builder can't be restarted, [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) say:

> The `liveData` building block serves as a structured concurrency primitive between coroutines and `LiveData`. The code block starts executing when `LiveData` becomes active and is automatically canceled after a configurable timeout when the `LiveData` becomes inactive. If it is canceled before completion, it is restarted if the `LiveData` becomes active again. **If it completed successfully in a previous run, it doesn't restart**. Note that it is restarted only if canceled automatically. If the block is canceled for any other reason (e.g. throwing a CancelationException), it is not restarted.

To make code run a couple of times I can suggest to create a function and call it when you need, e.g. on button click:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val topStoriesResult: LiveData<UIState<TopStoryWrapper>> = MutableLiveData<UIState<TopStoryWrapper>>()

    fun loadTopStories() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { // start a coroutine
        topStoriesRepository.getTopStoriesSetWrapper().apply {
            val mutableLiveData = loginResponse as MutableLiveData

            // post value to LiveData
            mutableLiveData.postValue(UIState.Loading)
            onFailure { mutableLiveData.postValue(UIState.NoData) }
            onSuccess { mutableLiveData.postValue(UIState.HasData(it)) }
        }
    }
}
```

To use `viewModelScope` in `MainViewModel` class add dependency to build.gradle file:

> final LIFECYCLE_VERSION = "2.2.0-rc03" // add most recent version
>
> api "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$LIFECYCLE_VERSION"

Comment: Then you aren't using the live data scope...